# Can't specify STATICFILES_DIRS correctly in Django

Tags: django

I'm getting the warning: (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'C:/frontend/build' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist. It seems like i'm not able to reference my react build folder correctly, all this happened after trying to move django api folders. Here is what my folders look like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcIBP.png)

And here's how my path related setting look like in my settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "frontend/build")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(
        BASE_DIR, "/frontend/build")
]
```

I've tried debugging my settings.py, it seems like the BASE_DIR is never set correctly, im not able to understand os.path.join

Answer (score -1):

Slashes were giving me a bad time. I solved it modifying my templates like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
    "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "frontend/build")],
    "APP_DIRS": True,
    "OPTIONS": {
        "context_processors": [
            "django.template.context_processors.debug",
            "django.template.context_processors.request",
            "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
            "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
        ],
    },
},
```

]

And my static files like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR, "frontend/build/static")
]
```